How to get the second best model parameter using pycaret?
This is my code on google collab
# Import library 
from pycaret.classification import *


exp_clf = setup(data, target='target', normalize=True)


best_model = compare_models()

And this is the result

this code will show the best model parameter
display(best_model)

and this is the result

I want to know the other model parameter instead of the best model (Light Gradient Boosting Machine) since the AUC is not high enough for me. How do i display the parameter for random forest classifier?
I tried this, hoping it will show me the parameter of the second best model (random forest)
 display(best_model[1])

and this is the result
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-63c1d322b8ae> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 display(best_model[1])

TypeError: 'LGBMClassifier' object is not subscriptable


You need to specify the n_select=<no_of_models_return> parameter in the compare_models() method by default n_select is set to 1 thus you get only 1 model.
Example code (I set verbose=False to hide some information)
from pycaret.datasets import get_data
from pycaret.classification import *

data = get_data('diabetes', verbose=False)
s = setup(data, target = 'Class variable', session_id = 123, verbose=False)
top3_best_models = compare_models(n_select=3, verbose=False) # Get top 3 best models

for model in top3_best_models:
    display(model)


